# How to draw use case diagram based on microservice architecture?

Tags: architecture, microservices, uml, use-case

I want to develop a web application based on Microservice architecture.So,I have drawn use case diagram describing functional requirements of the system, but I am not sure whether is it correct or not?

My system has three Microservices. The first one called "shop service" which is the main service that is responsible for everything happens at the online-shop: viewing product catalog, adding product to cart, filling in order information. It is represented as a rectangle on my diagram all the business processes(functions) happen within it.

The second one is bank service that is responsible for making payments using customer's bank account.

The third one is postal service that is responsible for delivering orders to customers to be able to receive it.

I have six actors. I also divide them into the primary and the secondary ones. The primary ones which are on the left initiate the use of the system, on the other hand, the secondary ones are more reactionary.

What would you recommend me to do my system to become more readable and understood for everyone? Should I add or delete something? Here is my attached diagram:

[image: use case diagram]

I apologize for all mistakes I have made asking the current question. Sorry for my bad English as well.

Answer (score 2):

Except for `Log in` that looks ok. `Log in` is no use case (no added value for the actor) but a simple constraint attached to certain UCs which need the authentication.

In order to group your microservices you could introduce different systems under consideration reflecting the specific microservices. The use cases related to each microservice would then appear inside the boundary reflecting the specific microservice.

On a further notice: UCs that are only attached to secondary actors (appearing to the right) I would consider them not being UCs but just a flow of events in the including UC. UCs are meant to show added value the system under consideration brings to its primary actor. The way you did it is just functional decomposition. That's not what UCs are all about.

And as always I recommend to read Bittner/Spence about use cases.

Comment: Very clear with good advice, as usual!  I was however wondering if it would be a good idea to break down the requirement by microservice, since a split by microservices is more about the internals of the solution and solution space, than requirements and problem space observed by the outside world and the actors (moreover, the outside wolrd would probably pass through an API gateway that would hide the details about which service is doing what).

Comment: @qwerty_so, thank you for your answer.As far as I understand, should I exclude the secondary actors on my diagram, shouldn't I?

Comment: @Christophe I was thinking of microservices as sub-domains. Since it's "micro" the question could be whether this makes sense since sub-domains usually break down complex structures in just manageable ones. It'd probably more an architectural question here.

Comment: @Vladislav No. You should remove the bubble "Make payment" and connect the "Bank service" directly with "Make order". If "Make payment" were an independent UC you should connect it with the primary actors. But if not, just remove it.

Comment: @qwerty_so, I got it. And one more question. Am I right considering adding bubble "Deliver order" in my rectangle is incorrect because the mentioned use case is a part of another system (postal service)?

Comment: I would say so. A UC diagram is intended to show primarily the added value for the primary actors. However, if you have complex systems, there can be the need to also show added values for secondary actors (because you have indirect strong relations to them). In that case you just shift the focus and you must be clear about that in the context. There is no "single UC diagram" but you create individual ones depending on what you need to express.

Comment: @qwerty_so Ok, this is indeed relevant if the architecture pattern of “service by sub-domain” was already decided, and alternative decomposition strategies excluded (see https://microservices.io/patterns/index.html under item Decomposition)